# Is it possible to set the Apache protocols directive conditionally 1-time rather than in all VirtualHost blocks?

Tags: apache-2.4

Rather than adding `protocols h2 http/1.1` in all 45 of my `VirtualHost *:443` blocks, I was wondering if there is way to check for the appropriate condtion and then set `protocols` based on that? I think, but not 100% certain, that the appropriate test should be to see if the request was for https. Maybe I should test port instead, though?

This is what I've got so far and it isn't working.

```
Define PROTOCOLS "http/1.1"

<If "%{HTTPS} == 'on'">
    Define PROTOCOLS "h2 http/1.1"
</If>

Protocols ${PROTOCOLS}
```

**Edit**

`Protocols` does not work in a directory context.

**Edit 2**

I just don't think it's possible, given that the `Protocols` directive, if defined globally, cannot be dynamically modified like this. The server has already parsed the directive. It's set. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#protocols):

> Protocols Directive
> Description:  Protocols available for a server/virtual host
> Syntax:   Protocols protocol ...
> Default:  Protocols http/1.1
> Context:  **server config**, virtual host

`Protocols` is allowed in the server config, not only in the virtual host. Just set it once outside of a VirtualHost and it is set for the whole server. You can then omit it in the VirtualHost definition.

A very simple configuration would be:

```conf
# define defaults
Protocols h2 http/1.1

# single VirtualHost for all HTTP redirects
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Protocols http/1.1
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</VirtualHost>

# Now all HTTPS VirtualHost definitions
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I want a different Protocols directive set on non-ssl enabled VirtualHosts

Comment: Since nowadays HTTP is only being used to redirect to HTTPS you can define a single VirtualHost for HTTP with the diverting Protocols definition.